# Symfony2: How to display admin-account name while impersonating user-account?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to display something like that:

**Case 1: "logged in as USER"**

> > @ UserName [ logout ]

No problems here, i just do:

*@ {{ app.user.username}} [ <a href="{{ path("logout") }}">logout</a> ]*

**Case 2: "logged in as ADMIN"**

> > @ AdminName [ logout ]

The same works here:

*@ {{ app.user.username}} [ <a href="{{ path("logout") }}">logout</a> ]*

**Case 3: "logged in as ADMIN impersonating a USER"**

> > AdminName @ UserName [ return ]

Now thats a problem:

{{ **??..what here..??** }} @ {{ app.user.username}} [ <a href="{{ (app.request.getRequestUri ~ '?_switch_user=_exit') }}">return</a> ]

This is the only solution I know... it seems a lot of code for a sipmle displaying username :/

```
{# iterating through user roles to find ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN #}
{% for role in app.security.token.roles %}
  {% if role.source is defined %}
    {{ role.source.user.username }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
@ {{ app.user.username }} [ <a href="{{ (app.request.getRequestUri ~ '?_switch_user=_exit') }}">return</a> ]
```

**Is there any other way?** I need a pure TWIG solution -> this is supposed to be part of my main twig template (that is extended by all other templates) -> I can't add controller code to all actions, just to display username.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in Symfony3? The app.security variable has been [deprecated since v2.6 and was removed in v3](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/twig_reference.html#app).

Comment: @user5670895 try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68294209/526495

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the idea you have proposed above,.. can you not just create a custom twig extension that encompasses your logic from your twig template so that you can just call `myCustomTwigFunction` within your twig template and it will output the original users name?

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html for more info about custom twig extensions

The code you'd have in your Twig extension file would be...

```
$roles = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getRoles();
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (method_exists($role, 'getSource')) {
        return ($role->getSource()->getUser()->getUsername());
    }
}
```

Where $container is a class variable of the DI Container on your twig extension class

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution for Symfony 4.3/4.4/5.0:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') %}
    {% for role in app.token.roles %}
        {% if role.role == 'ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN' %}
            Admin username is {{ role.source.user.username }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

From Symfony 5.1 onwards, use `IS_IMPERSONATOR` in place of `ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN`.